# Preventing an activity from occupying the full width of the screen

Tags: android

I have a dialog-style android activity that gets displayed on top of the main activity in my android app. I don't want it to take up the full width of the screen. How can I specify that it leaves a margin of x dp on either side of it?

Comment: android:layout_marginTop="yourdp" same for left right and bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. you can set the margin manually as said by @Raghunandan there.
2. you could set a custom theme to that particular activity which by default doesn't take up the full screen space. for that particular activity just add

`<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
LayoutParams lp = this.getWindow().getAttributes();
             lp.x=50;lp.y=20;lp.width=100;lp.height=200;lp.gravity=Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
            lp.dimAmount=0;            
            lp.flags=LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
this.setContentView(view, lp);
```